# repeat over list of object declaratively

Tags: polymer

I have yet another question: 
Why is that if I repeat over a list of objects from a template the element in the template cannot see the object when used declaratively?

```
artists = [ {name: 'whatever',..},...];
```

Example:

```
<template repeat="{{a in artists}}">
  <artist-record model="{{a}}"></artist-record>
</template>
```

If I do the same imperatively it works

Example

```
artists.forEach(function(a) {
  var node = document.createElement('artist-record');
  node.model = a;
  this.$.container.appendChild(node);
}, this);
```

Is there a way to do this declaratively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me: http://jsbin.com/zemawugu/1/edit

Check that your array assignment is to `this.artists` and not `artists`. The binding system needs that array to be on the element prototype for the template to see it.